# AngularJS. UI Bootstrap modal does not close on backdrop click when using custom styles

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap modal with custom styles. When using default Bootstrap styles, click on the backdrop element closes the modal, but when using custom styles, click on the backdrop element does nothing.

Below are code samples and the link to [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4REeovAu8L5MWSCZfFHO?p=preview). Custom CSS and Bootstrap CSS are linked in the head comment them out to check.

app.js

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('BodyCtrl', BodyCtrl);

BodyCtrl.$inject = ['$uibModal'];

function BodyCtrl($uibModal) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.openModal = openModal;

  function openModal() {
    var modal = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modal.html',
      controller: function() {

      },
      controllerAs: 'modal'
    })
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.4.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="BodyCtrl as body">
  <button type="button" ng-click="body.openModal()">Open modal</button>
</body>
</html>
```

modal.html

```
<h1>Modal</h1>
```

main.css

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS listens for a click on the .modal element, not the .modal-backdrop. With following changes to main.css it does work.

main.css

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```